# react + mobx example Attempted import error: 'useObservable' is not exported from 'mobx-react-lite'

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

please suggest the solution. the error which is shown on browser is

Failed to compile
./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'useObservable' is not exported from 'mobx-react-lite'.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {observer, useObservable} from 'mobx-react-lite';


const App = observer(() => {

const store = useObservable({
    count:1,
addOne(){
  store.count++;
},
subOne(){
  store.count--;
}
})

function addOneHandle(){
store.addOne();
}
function subOneHandle(){
store.subOne();
}

return (
 <div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
   <h1>Count: {store.count}</h1>
   <button onClick={addOneHandle}>Add 1</button>
   <button onClick={subOneHandle}>Sub 1</button>
  </header>
</div>
 );
 })

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `useObserver` not `useObservable`

Comment: If I try UseObserver I get the following error: TypeError: fn is not a function.  in src/useObserver.ts:123 with the line:  rendering = fn().  In package.json I have "mobx": "^5.15.4",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^2.0.7",

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useObserver, useLocalStore } from "mobx-react-lite";

const App = () => {
  // Creating our store
  const store = useLocalStore(() => ({
    count: 1,
    addOne() {
      store.count++;
    },
    removeOne() {
      store.count--;
    },
  }));

  const addOneHandle = () => {
    store.addOne();
  };
  const removeOneHandle = () => {
    store.removeOne();
  };

  return useObserver(() => (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>State management with MobX</h1>
        <h1>Count: {store.count} </h1>
        <button onClick={addOneHandle}>Add One</button>
        <button onClick={removeOneHandle}>Remove One</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  ));
};

export default App;
```

You can refer to the official docs...
https://mobx-react.js.org/observer-hook

Answer (score 0):

import { useObservable } from 'mobx-react-better-use-observable'

Answer (score 0):

```js
//use {useLocalObservable } instead of {useObservable } from "mobx-react-little";
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { observer, useLocalObservable } from "mobx-react-lite";

const App = observer(() => {
  const store = useLocalObservable(() => ({
    count: 1,
    addOne() {
      store.count++;
    },
    subOne() {
      store.count--;
    },
  }));

  function addOneHandle() {
    store.addOne();
  }
  function subOneHandle() {
    store.subOne();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Count: {store.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={addOneHandle}>Add 1</button>
        <button onClick={subOneHandle}>Sub 1</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Please, cold you explain your answer. What do you changed to make it working?

Comment: The code you posted is *not* a runnable snippet (just click the "Run..." button and you will realize that)! Please edit your answer and format your code as a **plain code block** instead (use simple, three back-tick code fences).

Comment: @Leo i changed {useObservable } to {useLocalObservable }  from "mobx-react-little" and  {useLocalObservable }  take an callBack function .

Comment: @AdrianMole it will not work here because it is an react app application code (give import error because all module it not available here)you need to create react app using npm then when you replace that code in App.js it will work .